# tkinter tkcalendar to display events

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am trying to use tkcalendar to display some events in my python tkinter application. I have a database of events and i put them in the calendar as in the following example (I have created a dictionary of events to show the case). In this example I loop over all events and put them all in the calendar

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkcalendar
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import datetime

root = tk.Tk()

events={'2018-09-28':('London','meeting'),\
    '2018-08-15':('Paris','meeting'),\
    '2018-07-30':('New York','meeting')}

cal = Calendar(root, selectmode='day', year=2018, month=8)

for k in events.keys():
    date=datetime.datetime.strptime(k,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
    cal.calevent_create(date, events[k][0], events[k][1])

cal.tag_config('meeting', background='red', foreground='yellow')
cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Up to now everything fine. The problem is that the database of events is quite large and expands several years. Ideally I would want to create only the events of the month being displayed. I need to detect when the user clicks on "Next month" and "Previous Month" (the standard buttons that come with the tkcalendar):
[image]

and create the events for the month being displayed. Is that even possible?

thank you very much in advance

Comment: You've told us what you're trying to do, but didn't ask a question (other than "is that even possible?"). What sort of help do you need? What have you tried to solve this? Perhaps you should start with events in only two to three months until you figure out how to display only the displayed month's events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class inheriting from `Calendar` and redefine the callbacks of the "Next month" and "Previous Month" buttons so that they generate a virtual event `'<<CalendarMonthChanged>>'`. Then bind this event to a function that displays the current month events.

Here is the code:

```
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from tkinter import Tk


class MyCalendar(Calendar):

    def _next_month(self):
        Calendar._next_month(self)
        self.event_generate('<<CalendarMonthChanged>>')

    def _prev_month(self):
        Calendar._prev_month(self)
        self.event_generate('<<CalendarMonthChanged>>')

    def _next_year(self):
        Calendar._next_year(self)
        self.event_generate('<<CalendarMonthChanged>>')

    def _prev_year(self):
        Calendar._prev_year(self)
        self.event_generate('<<CalendarMonthChanged>>')

    def get_displayed_month_year(self):
        return self._date.month, self._date.year


def on_change_month(event):
    # remove previously displayed events
    cal.calevent_remove('all')
    year, month = cal.get_displayed_month_year()
    # display the current month events 
    # ...
    print(year, month)

root = Tk()
cal = MyCalendar(root)
cal.pack()

cal.bind('<<CalendarMonthChanged>>', on_change_month)

root.mainloop()
```